# How to append multi row in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

My requirement is to make nested data in my form and each of this data has ability to add more rows or delete them. I have done such thing with JavaScript before but with VueJs it's my first attempt so I kind of need push :)

## Logic

[image: one]

1. Parent data has select option which will let user to select what
   type of input they need and based on that selection it append the
   input. (RED)
2. My parent data can be added or removed so i can have several parent
   and each of them several child at the same time (BLUE)
3. My child data can be added or removed (GREEN)

## Code

Here is my first static html (no script has written for it yet)

> Ps: all parts are commented.

```
<el-form-item label="Variation Name">
    <el-col :span="12">

        // parent
        <el-input placeholder="Please input your variation name" v-model="form.variationParent" class="input-with-select">
            // select type of child's input
            <el-select v-model="form.variationParent" slot="prepend" placeholder="Select">
                <el-option label="Text" value="1"></el-option>
                <el-option label="Text Area" value="2"></el-option>
                <el-option label="Boolean" value="3"></el-option>
            </el-select>
            <el-button slot="append" type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button> //add parent
            <el-button slot="append" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button> // delete parent
        </el-input>

    </el-col>

    <el-col class="line text-center" :span="3">Variation Value(s)</el-col>
    <el-col :span="9">

        // child's
        <el-input v-model="form.variationChilds" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select">
            <el-button slot="append" type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button> //add child
            <el-button slot="append" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button> // delete child
        </el-input>

    </el-col>
</el-form-item>
```

**Any kind of `idea` and `sample codes` are appreciated.**

## Update

I have manage to add and remove parent part with this code:

```
<el-form-item v-for="(index, k) in variationParents" :key="k" label="Variation Name">
    <el-col :span="12">

        <!-- parent -->
        <el-input placeholder="Please input your variation name" v-model="form.variationParent" class="input-with-select">
            <el-select v-model="form.variationParent" slot="prepend" placeholder="Select">
                <el-option label="Text" value="input"></el-option>
                <el-option label="Text Area" value="textarea"></el-option>
                <el-option label="Boolean" value="boolean"></el-option>
            </el-select>
            <el-button slot="append" @click="add(k)" type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button>
            <el-button slot="append" @click="remove(k)" v-show="k || ( !k == variationParents.lenghth > 1)" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
        </el-input>

    </el-col>

    <el-col class="line text-center" :span="3">Variation Value(s)</el-col>
    <el-col :span="9">

        <!-- child's -->
        <el-input v-model="form.variationChilds" placeholder="Please input your variation value" class="input-with-select">
            <el-button slot="append" type="success" icon="el-icon-plus"></el-button>
            <el-button slot="append" type="danger" icon="el-icon-delete"></el-button>
        </el-input>

    </el-col>
</el-form-item>

data() {
    return {
        variationParents: [
            {
                name: '',
                type: ''
            }
        ],
    }
},
methods: {
    add(index){
        this.variationParents.push({name: '', type: ''});
    },
    remove(index){
        this.variationParents.splice(index, 1);
    },
}
```

and here is the result + issue

[image: three]

As you see i have new rows of parents and `add / remove` buttons working but my inputs are all getting same value, meaning if i set first input to something all of them will get same value.

They need to each one have different value and be send to back-end as array.

Comment: @YomS. regarding to this question all i have is the html part that i included to the question but if you need i can make jsfiddle, yet all the code i have is this :)

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/robertnicjoo/c2d1xzeL/1/

Comment: Well, this fiddle looks completely different and irrelevant to your template in question. Please post some data or scripts you have tried so far.

Comment: The reason you're getting shared values is because you are doing `v-model` on different object (`form`) instead of what's being looped in the `v-for`.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't actually run your jsfiddle, but looking at your code I think you're pretty close, only, as I said in the comment, you need to bind these input/form elements on the individual `variationParents` being looped with `v-for`.

Here's some quick example that shows how to sync those parent values across the components. I couldn't add everything for you though.

Also, as you scale, you might want to consider using Vuex for better management of states.

```js
const variationNames = ['Text', 'Text Area', 'Boolean'];

const VariationBar = Vue.extend({
  template: '#variation-bar',
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      // This simply ensures that the `name` property 
      // be validated against the list, while binding;
      // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation
      validator: val => variationNames.includes(val)
    },
    values: {
      type: Array
    }
  },

  data: () => ({
    variationNames
  }),

  computed: {
    // Read more here on how computed setter works:
    // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter
    inputName: {
      get() {
        return this.name;
      },
      set(val) {
        // When setter gets invoked, emit the new value
        // and notify the parent that it needs to "sync" it.
        // This works hand-in-hand with the `.sync` modifier
        // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier
        this.$emit('update:name', val);
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    addValue() {
      // Add your default item/preset here
      this.values.push({
        text: ''
      })
    },
    removeValue(index) {
      this.values.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: vm => ({
    variations: [{
      name: 'Boolean',
      values: [
        { text: 'Core i3' },
        { text: 'Core i5' }
      ]
    }]
  }),

  methods: {
    addVariation() {
      this.variations.push({
        name: 'Text',
        values: [
          { text: 'Core i3' }
        ]
      });
    },
  },

  components: {
    VariationBar
  }
})
```

```css
.variation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <variation-bar v-for="item of variations" :key="item.name" :name.sync="item.name" :values="item.values" @variation:add="addVariation">
  </variation-bar>
  
  <pre>{{variations}}</pre>
</div>

<template id="variation-bar">
  <div class="variation">
    <div class="variation__col">
      <label>Variation Name</label>
      <select v-model="inputName">
        <option
          v-for="name of variationNames" :key="name"
          :value="name"
          v-text="name">
        </option>
      </select>

      <div class="variation__btn-group">
        <button @click="$emit('variation:add')">add</button>
        <button @click="$emit('variation:remove')">remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="variation__col">
      <label>Variation values(s)</label>

      <div
        v-for="(val, index) of values" :key="`${val.text}-${index}`"
        class="variation__value">
        <input type="text" v-model.lazy="val.text" />

        <div class="variation__btn-group">
          <button @click="addValue">add</button>
          <button @click="removeValue(index)">remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks for answer man, would you mind to comment each part so i can understand where to place them or what each one does? for instance right now anywhere i place those `const` it's breaking some other part. :/

Comment: Do you mean the `variationNames` const in my example? Where and how did you use it? That was actually for prop checking only.

Comment: I added some inline comments on the example. I might actually be able to help you with the real code (your app in question) if you could just get the jsfiddle to work, and the issue reproducible. As it stands, I couldn't even run it. Too many missing info on the fiddle. But that's up to you.

Comment: thanks, how if i give you my component? would that help you? i just send you full component?

Comment: this is my full component here http://collabedit.com/ywheq and i commented issue part so you can find it easily

Comment: @mafortis Well, I really expected it to be [minimal and reproducible snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But anyway, I got a lot of warnings while trying to compile, even with most of the extraneous parts stripped off. It's complaining that `Injection of elForm not found`... I don't use ElementUI, so no idea how to even fix that.

Comment: It doesn't look like it could compile anyway. You seem to be mistaking the individual items for their indices when you do `v-for="(index, k) in variationParents"`.

Comment: And what about this line `v-show="b || (!b == variationChilds.lenghth > 1)"`? Sorry, but that looks pretty garbled. Particularly this part `lenghth`...

Comment: Sorry mate, but I'll just leave this for you to figure out. I believe I've added enough information by the example above for you to tinker with. Good luck!

Comment: hi, no problem man you get el errors because you don't have element ui installed otherwise code doesn't have issue i am using it daily. i have 2 v-for one for parents and other one for childs as i explained each parent has several childs so i need to use 2 v-for.  would you just tell me one thing please? if for example in my childs i use `indexx.name` for v-model i can get different inputs which is what i wanted but how to pass them as array in my v-model?

Comment: I did have ElementUI installed. It turned out you need to wrap these `<el-* />` components in an `<el-form />` to fix the warnings. Anyways, regarding your last question on having the right reference for the children (being looped in `v-for`), and as seen in my example, I would add them as an array of object, nested in the parent (see the `variations` object in `data` section), and when you iterate over them, you could simply do e.g. `variationItem.values[index].text`.

Comment: it becomes so complected and i'm not understand any part of it. thanks anyway i probably give up on that!